# Not finding the usual QueryRequest.withKeyConditions() method(Dynamo DB)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am new to Dynamo DB. I'm using Amazon DDb documentation to implement the QUERY method. I am trying to do something similar to the example provided(the replies for a thread example).

I am not able to find the 'withKeyConditionsMethod' under QueryRequest. What is it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the older version of the api (in the java package `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.model`) then the syntax is a little different, and you have to use `withRangeKeyCondition`.  Here's the `QueryRequest` class with that older version, you can see how it's deprecated:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/model/QueryRequest.html

If you are using the newer version of the API (which you should, in the java package `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model`, then you will see that the `QueryRequest` has the `withKeyConditions` method, as shown here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/QueryRequest.html